# Firefox opacity issue: text gets weird, colored outlines if container opacity < 1.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

This doesn't happen in Chrome or Safari. It's a little bit noticeable in IE8, but very slight (and gray). The outline I see on both my monitors is greenish. I don't know if it's an issue with my graphics card or with Firefox's rendering of fonts at different opacities.

It happens whether or not the style is set CSS statically, not using the jQuery `fadeTo()` effect.

The following test page shows the problem. Move your mouse from top left to bottom right to change the opacity. Eventually you get to an opacity of 1.0, at which point everything is fine. Any ideas why this might be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>
        Text Opacity Test
      </title>
      <style type="text/css">
            body {
              background-color: #ddd;
            }
            div#textDiv {
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              right: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              padding: 20px;
              font-size: 400%;
              color: white;
            }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            $(document).ready( function() {
                $(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){ 
                    var hOpacity = (e.pageX / Math.round($('#textDiv').width())/2);
                    var vOpacity = (e.pageY / Math.round($('#textDiv').height())/2);
                    var opacity = vOpacity + hOpacity;
                    opacity = (opacity > 1) ? 1.0 : (opacity < 0) ? 0 : opacity;
                    $("#textDiv").text('Opacity: ' + opacity.toFixed(2));
                    $('#textDiv').fadeTo(0, opacity);
                });
            });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="textDiv"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: No issues here, Firefox 3.6.3 / Mac OS X 10.4.11

Comment: I notice a *very* slight border around my characters, due to not completely optimal sub-pixel anti-aliasing; FF 3.6.11 / Linux. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @jncpl & @Marcel Korpel: This box is running Windows 7. Thanks for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is a problem with text and opacity in FF. You just need to set a background color to the element that you are changing the opacity.

If you can't (eg: the text is on various background) well... You are screwed :D

Dunno if it's working, but you can set `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`, maybe you are in luck.

Comment: Bravo. Setting a background color on `#textDiv` fixed the problem. Thanks. But you're right, this will be a problem in cases where I can't use a background-color on the container.

Comment: Thanks for this Ionut. Helped me with this problem too!!